# SafeConfigParser: sections and environment variables

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-3.4, configparser

(*Using Python 3.4.3*)

I want to use environment variables in my config file and I read that I should use `SafeConfigParser` with `os.environ` as parameter to achieve it.

```
[test]
mytest = %(HOME)s/.config/my_folder
```

Since I need to get all the options in a section, I am executing the following code:

```
userConfig = SafeConfigParser(os.environ)
userConfig.read(mainConfigFile)
for section in userConfig.sections():
    for item in userConfig.options(section):
        print( "### " + section + " -> " + item)
```

My result is not what I expected. As you can see below, it got not only the option I have in my section (`[test]\mytest`), but also all the environment variables:

```
### test -> mytest
### test -> path
### test -> lc_time
### test -> xdg_runtime_dir
### test -> vte_version
### test -> gnome_keyring_control
### test -> user
```

What am I doing wrong?

I want to be able to parse `[test]\mytest` as `/home/myuser/.config/my_folder` but don't want the `SafeConfigParser` adding all my environment variables to each one of its sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood your question and what you want to do correctly, you can avoid the problem by  ***not*** supplying `os.environ` as parameter to `SafeConfigParser`. Instead use it as the `vars` keyword argument's value when you actually retrieve values using the `get()` method.

This works because it avoids creating a *default* section from all your environment variables, but allows their values to be used when referenced for interpolation/expansion purposes.

```
userConfig = SafeConfigParser()  # DON'T use os.environ here
userConfig.read(mainConfigFile)

for section in userConfig.sections():
    for item in userConfig.options(section):
        value = userConfig.get(section, item, vars=os.environ)  # use it here
        print('### [{}] -> {}: {!r}'.format(section, item, value))
```

Comment: The problem is, if I have %(HOME)s defined in the ini file and not give the os.environ to the SafeConfigParser(), the sections() will crash because it doesn't know how to handle HOME.

Comment: Weird. Ok, I'll try again in a clean class and see if you tip solves the problem. THanks, Martineau