# Is it possible to use environment variables in python logging config?

Tags: python, logging

If yes, what is the syntax? For example, in `logging.conf` I would like to do something like this:

```
[DEFAULT]
log_dir = $(LOG_DIR)

...

[handler_root]
level=INFO
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
formatter=standardFormatter
args=("%(log_dir)s/my.log","midnight",1,14)
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, by parsing the config file with

[SafeConfigParser()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser)

related question here:
[SafeConfigParser: sections and environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39408101/safeconfigparser-sections-and-environment-variables)

Comment: You are telling me how to access env var from a python script. But this is not what I am asking.

Comment: But I am not parsing config explicitly, python default logging does. Do you know how to tell logging to use `SafeConfigParser`?